# Weird background-image behaviour in Firefox – displayed locally, but not online?

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

I have this page, and I use a background-image on the body. I'm a professional web-developer, and have done this literally thousands of times, so I'm by no means a beginner.

Anyway, the background-image displays in Safari and Chrome, and also when testing locally in Firefox. As soon as I upload the page and test it online, it no longer displays in Firefox (the other browsers are fine).

Firebug tells me that the image loads just fine, and the path is correct.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the cause of this? I think I checked all possible 'culprits', and as mentioned, everything is fine in Safari and Chrome, both locally and online.

You can see the page here:
https://ssl.director.dk/clients/pfmb/index.html

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('../img/adbg.jpg');
    background-color: #000000;  
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

Please help, because this is driving me crazy.

Cheers

Hans

Comment: i can see one person image in backgropund..?? is that you can't see.?

Comment: Loads for me in Firefox on Mac OS X. Maybe you have a broken copy of the image in your cache? You could try emptying it.

Comment: Probably not related but your reset css file should be loaded before your main css file. Also you're saying on your body tag line-height:1.5 but not specifying a unit e.g. em, px.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes, the person is missing in FF. Billy Moat: line-height is defined as a multiple, that's why there's no unit – that's on purpose.

Comment: All I can suggest is that this may be some sort of cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

your `<body>` renders with this attribute: `background="img/adbg.jpg"`

Perhaps it is overriding your CSS. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: The OP's not having any issues with Chrome. It *shouldn't* be an issue, but as you say, it isn't good style, so it *could* be the issue...

Comment: oh, I overread the part about browsers, thanks. (Edit: works for me in FF, too, though)

Comment: Thank for your answers. Defining the background as html-property was one of my experiments, that's why it's there. I already flushed caches, but I'll try again.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed with caches is that sometimes I flush it but it actually doesn't flush the image for some reason... So I navigate directly to the image (open it up in a new tab) and do a cache-refresh there, and that updates it. If the answer I offered wasn't correct, then I have no idea, but give that refresh a try if you haven't already. Good luck!